# Is there a way to light stuff on fire without attacking it?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I'm playing **Assassin's Creed: Odyssey** (PC via Steam, all DLC). When I equip my torch, I know I can light stuff on fire by attacking it. Is there another way to do it?

When I played Origins, there were certain objects that Bayek would just light if you stood next to them holding a torch. Braziers (regular ones not the alarm ones), sconces, mounted torches, that sort of thing -- simply hold the torch, stand close enough, and Bayek would reach out and light them. I found this very useful not just because I am a pyromaniac and I like setting things on fire, but also because I could use it to track where I'd been. For example, if I was sneaking through a pyramid, I'd light all braziers as I went down a corridor, so if I had to backtrack to go down different side passages I'd always be able to tell where I'd been previously.

Example -- the brazier on the right of this screenshot snippet was lit by standing near it holding a torch.

[image: AC Origins lit brazier]

This mechanic seems to be missing from Odyssey. (In general, the "stand or crouch nearby and the character will do it automatically" mechanic seems to be missing, come to think of it. In addition to lighting things on fire, Bayek would also pet cats, for example.)

When I have Kassandra hold the torch and stand close to an unlit brazier ... well nothing happens. Standing or crouching, she makes no move to light the brazier. The only way I've figured out to do this is to actually "attack" the brazier with the torch. Unfortunately, Kassandra's torch attack is a wide arching swing, so we usually end up not only lighting the brazier, but also the wall, the roof, innocent civilians, and sometimes ourselves on fire as well.

Fire arrows are, of course, an alternative ... but that seems a waste of arrows. Other than these two methods (torch attack and fire arrows), **is there another simpler/less wasteful way to light things on fire?** (I'm specifically interested in lighting things like non-alarm braziers on fire; the torch attack/fire arrow is fine for destroying military supplies on missions.)

Comparative example: Kassandra can stand here with her torch next to this brazier all day and will never just light it.

[image: AC Odyssey unlit brazier]

Comment: I remember seeing a video where Bayek crouched to examine a corpse and accidentally lit the oil on the ground, immolating himself in the process all while calmly examining the corpse's cause of death, then burning to death himself shortly afterwards. It was pretty funny, though I guess that may have been the reason why this mechanics has been removed in Odyssey.

Comment: The fire mechanics were _fantastic_ and realistic. There's a video on reddit where Bayek stands too close to some scrolls, sets them on fire, and catches on fire himself. Then he drops and rolls to put himself out -- but has forgotten to drop the torch first so he happens to set _more_ scrolls on fire ... it's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you'd count this as attacking, but you can *throw* torches in addition to swinging them. Right click to aim when holding the torch, left click to throw.

This gives you better precision than attacking and, unlike fire arrows, doesn't cost anything.

You can also use this technique to create a light source down a corridor, or, apparently, [to light arrows on fire](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/help/assassins-creed-odyssey/gameplay/article/using-torches-in-assassins-creed-odyssey/000072655) (which I haven't tried out myself).

Comment: Yeah, drop the torch and then you can use it to light arrows. Same mechanic was present in Origins. That being said -- here's a protip. Make sure the arrow you're lighting on fire _isn't one of your explosive arrows_.